# parse server(back4app) rest api for creating object gives error 401

Tags: parse-platform, back4app

I am learning creating object on back4app parse server. i want to create it via rest not using sdk.
there is curl and python documentation on official site but not for javascript. i am using react native for now i tried using FETCH as well as AXIOS, non of this is working(gives 401)error
Here is what i am trying

```
async function addCustomClassName(){
try{
axios({
method:'POST',
url:'https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/MyCustomClassName',
Headers:{
"X-Parse-Application-Id": "the keys",
"X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "the keys",
"Content-Type": "application/json"
},
data:{"myCustomKey1Name":"myCustomKey1Value","myCustomKey2Name":"myCustomKey2Value"}
 }).then((res)=>{
  console.log(res)
 }).catch((err)=>{
 console.log(err.request )
 })
}
catch(error){
console.log(error)}}
```

can some body help?
thank you good people of stack overflow.

Comment: Try `headers` instead of `Headers`

Comment: @DaviMacêdo worked. thank you so much

Comment: @bikashamit Please make sure to change your REST API key since you have already exposed it over here.